# Add or subtract beyond 180 degrees in DOTween

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not able to rotate my x axis beyond +180/-180 degrees angle. I guess it is because I am using euler angles in DOTween?

How do I make sure it goes beyond 180 degrees?

```
this.transform.DORotate(this.transform.eulerAngles + new Vector3(90, 0, 0), 2f);
```

The reason i am doing this is because I am rotating a carousel in the x axis. So i want to always add 90 degrees and rotate in the same axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

targetOrigin.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
I had to set the RotateMode. If anyone faces this issue, here is the solution I found:

```
this.transform.DORotate(new Vector3(90, 0, 0), 0.25f, RotateMode.LocalAxisAdd).SetRelative(true).SetEase(Ease.Linear)
```

This will add +90 to axis every time you rotate your object.

Comment: You may accept your own answer, if you want.

Comment: @XouDo need to wait 2 days for that ;)

Comment: Ok I didn't know this one rule!